# Fishing Difficulty Differences?

Tags: terraria

Would there be a difference in the things I get from fishing or even an increased chance on getting an item by going to say expertmode, expert hardmode, hardmode, or even normal mode?

Comment: I think you can't get crates in easy mode from fishing, they are only obtainable in hard mode

Comment: @Alex Crates are available in both normal mode and Hardmode, they just have different contents if opened in Hardmode. e.g. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wooden_Crate

Comment: @Michaellogg Probably because Mythiral, Clorophyte, and other hard mode ores are obtainable through crates

Comment: @Alex Chlorophyte isn't available through crates, only the first three tiers of Hardmode ores (both varieties).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes to Hardmode, no to Expert Mode

Expert Mode has no effect on the fishing mechanics at all.

There are a number of catches that can only be made while Hardmode is activated, however, such as the [Obsidian Swordfish](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Obsidian_Swordfish) and the [Scaly Truffle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Scaly_Truffle). Further, crates that you catch can have different contents when opened during Hardmode, such as bars of Hardmode ores. Thus, you may want to wait to open any crates you catch in normal mode until you activate Hardmode, for a chance at better drops.

Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fishing